# Consolidating two methods into one

Tags: java, refactoring

I recently went through a code review, and it was firmly *suggested* that I consolidate two methods into one. Both methods are identical, save for a single method call in each, and one does not require an argument.

**Method #1**

```
private void updateCache(List<CategoryObject> objectList) {
    ServiceApi serviceApi = getService();
    if (serviceApi != null) {
        try {
            serviceApi.updateResources(objectList);
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Method #2**

```
private void registerCache() {
    ServiceApi serviceApi = getService();
    if (serviceApi != null) {
        try {
            serviceApi.registerCategory(CATEGORY_NAME);
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Can these even be efficiently combined?

Comment: If I were to refactor these two methods, I'd leave them distinct. Their intents are different, so for readability, the method names should reflect that. But I'd change the common part of both methods: the error handling. The caller doesn't get a notification whatsoever if the service isn't there or throws a BusinessException. I'd have the serviceApi==null case and the BusinessException throw something out of the method, so your caller gets informed.

Comment: *firmly suggested* :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull the inner functionality out into an interface:

```
private interface Op {
    void perform(ServiceApi serviceApi);
}

static void cache(Op op) {
    ServiceApi serviceApi = getService();
    if (serviceApi != null) {
        try {
            op.perform(serviceApi);
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }

}

private void updateCache(List<CategoryObject> objectList) {
    cache(new Op() {
        @Override
        public void perform(ServiceApi serviceApi) {
            serviceApi.updateResources(objectList);
        }
    });
}

private void registerCache() {
    cache(new Op() {
        @Override
        public void perform(ServiceApi serviceApi) {
            serviceApi.registerCategory(CATEGORY_NAME);
        }
    });
}
```

In Java 8 the two methods become truly simple and elegant.

```
private void updateCache(List<CategoryObject> objectList) {
    cache(serviceApi -> serviceApi.updateResources(objectList));
}

private void registerCache() {
    cache(serviceApi -> serviceApi.registerCategory(CATEGORY_NAME));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. I neglected to mention this, but `serviceApi` is an OSGi service that needs to be looked up on each use. In your Java 8 example, is `serviceApi` a class field?

Comment: @fojalar - `serviceApi` is the brand new one just obtained and passed to the `op` when `op.perform(serviceApi);` happens. It should function in exactly the same way as your original code. Look at the Java-7 versions first to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use one method and differentiate by the input parameter:

```
private void updateCache(List<CategoryObject> objectList) {
    ServiceApi serviceApi = getService();
    if (serviceApi != null) {
        try {
            if(objectList != null){
                serviceApi.updateResources(objectList);                
            }
            else{
                serviceApi.registerCategory(CATEGORY_NAME);
            }
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe the method name should be refactored as well then: `handleCache()`?

You then can call the method in 2 ways:

`handleCache(objectList)` --> works like method #1

`handleCache(null)` --> works like method #2